# PHP Session from Ajax form not saving session

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function

I've been trying to fix this on my own without any help, but I can't figure this out.

I'm submitting a form through via AJAX request but when I try to start a session on the other page, it sometimes doesn't create the session sometimes.

index.php:

```
session_start();
// SELECT COMMUNITY NAME FROM URL
$communityID = $_GET['id'];
$accessCode = $_GET['access'];
require '/scripts/config.php';
if($_SESSION['start'] == "".$communityID.""){
  echo $_SESSION['start'];
} else {
  echo "Session not started.";
}

<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#edit_button').on('click', function (event) {
              event.preventDefault();

              // Get form data
              var formData = $('#edit_form').serialize();

              // Get values from input
              var communityID = document.getElementById('value').value;

              // Make Ajax request
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '/scripts/main_forms.inc.php',
                  data: formData,
                  success: function (response) {
                      if (response.indexOf('success') !== -1) {
                          // Redirect if successful
                          window.location.href = "https://www.URL.com/"+communityID;
                      } else {
                          // Handle the response
                          $('.error').html(response);
                      }
                  },
                  error: function () {
                      alert('Error processing the form');
                  }
              });
          });
      });

      </script>

      <form id="edit_form" method="POST" style="display: none;">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" name="access_code" id="access_code" placeholder="6-Digit code" maxlength="6"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="communityID" id="value" value="<?php echo $communityID; ?>"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="edit_button" value="Edit community"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><div class="error"></div></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </form>
```

main_forms.inc.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require '/func/form_process.inc';

if (isset($_POST['access_code'])) {
    $code = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['access_code']);
    $communityID = $_POST['communityID'];

    $formData = accessCode($connect, $code, $communityID);

    if (!$formData) {

        $_SESSION['start'] = "".$communityID."";
        if(isset($_SESSION['start'])){
            echo "success";
            
            session_write_close();
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Error: Session not started.";
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        echo $formData[0];
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

form_process.inc.php:

```
function accessCode($connect, $code, $communityID){
    $errors = array();

    if(!$code){
        $errors[] = "A 6-digit code is required.";
        return $errors;
    }

    $accessQuery = "SELECT * FROM communities WHERE community='$communityID' AND access_code='$code' LIMIT 1";
    $accessNumrows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $accessQuery));
    if($accessNumrows == 0){
        $errors[] = "Access code not valid.";
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

The form is submitting correctly, and displaying error messages correctly. When the ajax request is successful, it displays 'success' which tells the AJAX script to reload to index.

Sessions are't starting first time round. session_start(); is at the top of every page.

The favicon also isn't loading, which makes me think there's a storage issue, or cache issue.

What could this be?

Comment: Do some debug, then share the debug results, make sure you are enabling the error log, check your PHP & web server error logs.